# How to tell Eclipse content assist not change my input?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-2020-03

I have recently installed Eclipse 2020-03.

Now, every time I have a `Map`, may it be called `myMap`, and try to type the following

```
myMap.put(
```

this gets automatically replaced by

```
myMap.compute(key, remappingFunction)
```

in the moment I type the `(`. The term `compute` is the first match in the list.

How can I type `myMap.put(` without it being replaced (and without using the arrow keys every time to choose the correct item from the list)?

Comment: You'll want to report it as a bug using bugs.eclipse.org.

Comment: @nitind I am not sure this is a bug. It is inconvenient matching behaviour. If I type something that is exactly in the list of suggestions, it would be great if it was not just replaced by the first item of that list.

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your example, since the first proposal is `put` in my case. Anyway, you can change the behavior by doing the following:

In *Window > **Preferences: Java > Editor > Content Assist*** check the checkbox ***Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'***